# Accessing action instance variables and model-driven bean variable values in JSP

Tags: struts2, ognl

I have `searchKey` as a variable in action class and model-driven bean object.

```
public class PaymentGateWayAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<PaymentResponseDTO> {
    private String searchKey;
    private PaymentResponseDTO paymentResponseDTO = new PaymentResponseDTO();
    // ...
}
```

`searchKey` is also a variable in `PaymentResponseDTO`.

I need to access `searchKey` from the action class and modeldriven bean based on some conditions. Having varible with same name is bad. But The above one is already developed. If I do any modification in Java file, I need to do many modifications which are difficult.

Now I need to access the action class variable. I tried to access the variable from action class in the follwing way:

```
<s:hidden id="searchKey" name="searchKey" value="%{searchKey}"/>
```

But it is returning null values.

I have below code also:

```
this.setSearchKey("somevarible");
```

Please suggest where the wrong is going on

**struts.xml**

```xml
<action name="atomResponse" class="com.PaymentGateWayAction" method="atomPaymentResponse">
  <result name="success" type="tiles">paymentGateWayResponse</result>
    <result name="failure" type="tiles">paymentGateWayResponseError</result>
  </action>
```

**tiles xml**

```xml
<definition name="paymentGateWayResponse" extends="b2cHome">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="agent_b2c/b2c_paymentGateWayResponse.jsp" />
</definition>
```

In `b2c_paymentGatewayResponse.jsp` the hidden field code is present.

Comment: i don't seem to understand your question. do you have `searchKey` both as a variable in your action class and model-driven bean. Do you have getters and setters for the `searchKey` variable.

Comment: @UchennaNwanyanwu.. I have searchKey as variable in action and model-driven bean, and i have setter and getters for searchKey

Comment: you didn't answer the first question. do you have `searchKey` as a variable in your action class and also in your model driven bean.

Comment: @UchennaNwanyanwu... yeah. I have searchKey as a variable in both..

Comment: the searchKey in your Model driven takes precedence since your Action class implements `ModelDriven`.

Comment: @UchennaNwanyanwu.. thank u for giving the solutions.. can't i access instance variable rather than model driven . Is there any way to access that variable

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When both your model (on top of the stack) and your action (generally the item below the model) have properties of the same name you can disambiguate using either the `#action` value stack context variable, or by directly accessing the stack (bad idea).

```html
<!-- Access action properties directly: -->
<s:property value="%{searchKey}" />          <!-- Model; top of stack.       -->
<s:property value="%{#action.searchKey}" />  <!-- Action; accessed directly. -->

<!-- Hope the stack never changes: -->
<s:property value="%{[0].searchKey}" />  <!-- Model;  top of stack.   -->
<s:property value="%{[1].searchKey}" />  <!-- Action; next stack pos. -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've had to face this issue several times but ended up renaming the property in the action class. I suggest that this be made available in `Struts2` documentation.

Comment: @UchennaNwanyanwu I made a brief note of it on the S2 OGNL page, but it won't get updated for awhile.

Comment: if I want to add this value inside a h2 dir attribute. how can it be? e.g. <h2 dir="<s:property value='%{#action.variableName}'"></h2>